# 2D numpy array: Remove lines that contain only empty tuples

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a 2d numpy array that contains tuple with two elements: an int and an str.

An example on how the 2d array may look:

```py
matrix = np.array(
[[(1, 'foo'), (), (4, 'bar')],
 [(),(),()],
 [(1, 'foo'), (), (3, 'foobar')],
 [(),(),()]], 
dtype=object)
```

I'm looking to remove the lines that contains only empty tuples.

I tried the following code:

```py
matrix = matrix[~np.all(matrix == (), axis=1)]
```

but it gave me the following error:

`numpy.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0`

The above code works for a 2d array that contains only integers with a condition like that in the `all` function: `matrix == 0`.
It correctly removes all lines that contains only zeros. So is there a way to do that but instead of removing lines with only zeros, to remove lines with only empty tuples?

Comment: Should you really use numpy for this? you won't benefit from vectorization. A python list would be more appropriate IMO…

Comment: Test all pieces of that expression to determine exactly what is producing that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that tuples are Sequence Types. When you try to apply `matrix == ()`, Numpy makes a comparison of matrices, and so `matrix == ()` return a simple `false`.

This explains the error `axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0`, since `false` is of dimension 0.

A workaround is to test differently if a tuple is empty, for example by vectorizing the len function:

```py
>>> vect_len = np.vectorize(len)
```

Then, we can do:

```py
>>> matrix = matrix[~np.all(vect_len(matrix) == 0, axis=1)]
[[(1, 'foo') () (4, 'bar')]
 [(1, 'foo') () (3, 'foobar')]]
```

Or even more simple:

```py
>>> matrix = matrix[np.any(vect_len(matrix), axis=1)]
[[(1, 'foo') () (4, 'bar')]
 [(1, 'foo') () (3, 'foobar')]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to traverse the array with a for loop and check if a sublist is made only with empty tuples with `all()` function:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[(1, 'foo'), (), (4, 'bar')], [(), (), ()], [(1, 'foo'), (), (3, 'foobar')], [(), (), ()]])

for i in range(len(matrix)):
    try:
        if all(x == () for x in matrix[i]):
            matrix = np.delete(matrix, i, axis=0)
    except:
        pass
print(matrix)
```

**Output:**

```
[[(1, 'foo') () (4, 'bar')]
 [(1, 'foo') () (3, 'foobar')]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, **do not use numpy** here. Numpy is for numbers. You don't have numbers. Numpy arrays may be able to hold `object` but there's no benefit here, and you run into problems as you've seen.

You can just use a "list comprehension" and the `all()` function to *filter* your data.

```py
lines = [
 [(1, 'foo'), (), (4, 'bar')],
 [(),(),()],
 [(1, 'foo'), (), (3, 'foobar')],
 [(),(),()]]

lines = [ line for line in lines if not all(elem == () for elem in line) ]
```

Comment: Maybe OP is forced to use Numpy, its use seems not usual here.

Comment: We'll let OP explain.

Comment: Ok thank your for your answer. I'm a beginner in python and I thought that you'll always have more reasons to use numpy than vanilla python list since each time I was looking for an operation to do on a array, I'll often get a numpy answer.

EDIT: Just saw the others answers. No I'm not forced to use numpy, like I said I'm a beginner in Python and so I thought that for everything as far as arrays are concerned, it was better to use numpy array instead of vanilla python array.

Comment: yeah don't worry, numpy is powerful, but it can't speed up anything with this kind of data (anything but only-numbers). sticking arbitrary objects into a numpy array _can_ be convenient for the indexing and slicing though, if a problem needs that.